# How to consider string with so many special words as one complete string in java?

Tags: java

I want to take String as input in java which contains so many special characters.

How to take whole string as input?

```
String str="<sub:SubmissionDetails xmlns:sub="http://www.cmcltd.com/facts/submissiondetails"> ";
```

I want to take this whole string as input.

Comment: you can try escaping?

Comment: use escape character \ in front of "

Comment: or use [StringExcapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache.

Comment: @Karthik Thats what I dont want to do? I know that solution. But i want to know that is there is any other way to do that? because for so many special character it will be to much time consuming

Comment: @MahekShah I couldnt see so many special characters in the posted code here

Comment: Karthik This is the example..It has so many

Answer (score -1):

You can use Apache Commons Lang as a lib in your project and use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` method.

[Method API Description](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String))

[Library Link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

It'll look like this:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("<sub:SubmissionDetails xmlns:sub="http://www.cmcltd.com/facts/submissiondetails"> ");
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile because it has unescaped special characters in the string.